# How to use JSON_INSERT with the key that is in string?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-json

I'm not finding a way to use JSON_INSERT in a json whose key is a string:

```
{
 "computer": {
    "display": blue
  },
 "computer home":{}
}
```

This way it works:

```
JSON_INSERT(type, '$.computer.color', 'red');`
```

But not like this:

```
JSON_INSERT(type, '$.computer home.color', 'red');`
```

My wish:

```
{
 "computer" :{
    "display": "blue",
    "color": "red"

  },
 "computer home":{
   "color": "red"
 }
}
```

Apparently it's not working because the json key "computer home" has space, how can I insert it even with spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> set @j = '{
 "computer": {
    "display": "blue"
  },
 "computer home":{}
}';
```

(note I had to put "blue" in double-quotes too; all strings must be delimited that way in JSON)

You can use JSON keys that contain spaces (or punctuation too) by delimiting them with double-quotes:

```
mysql> select json_insert(@j, '$."computer home".color', 'red') as result;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| result                                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"computer": {"display": "blue"}, "computer home": {"color": "red"}} |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```